# Common symbol for set of $n$ times differentiable functions

Tags: derivatives, notation

Is there a common symbol for the set of $n$ times differentiable functions? I need it all the time and all I know of is the symbol for continuously differentiable functions, $C^n$.

$D^n$ doesn't seem like a good idea, since I don't want to use the same symbol for an operator and its domain.

What about $D_n$?

Comment: In my experience $D^n$ refers strictly to the operator and not to a class. If you accept Diff($A,B$) as the class of differentiable functions from $A$ to $B$ (I've seen this used), then you could define Diff$^n(A)$, say, as the class of $n$-times differentiable functions on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you use, it is important that you mention the meaning of your notation, especially if it is something not so common as in this case.

Now, regarding the question, I can think of these:

- The notation $[D^n]^{-1}[\mathbb R^A]$ is technically correct but cumbersome ($\mathbb R^A$ is the set of functions from $A$ to $\mathbb R$).
- I guess you could use $\operatorname{Dom}(D^n)$, for the domain of the $n$-th derivative operator.

I leave this as community wiki so that people can add their suggestions.